# tvOS app starts crashing on the latest tvOS update

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tvos, nib

I have a pretty basic tvOS app. It uses storyboard named 'Main'. Before a week ago, all was fine. It would load no problems at all. I installed 17.2 on my Apple TV, and it crashes as soon as it opens. I tested this out in Xcode and it runs on a 17.0 simulator, but the 17.2 simulator crashes and the only message I get is

```
Exception   NSException *   "Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Tyler/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A442BA1A-318B-43EC-850E-EA0CFA7AAB95/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CC57DE61-B9E4-49EE-A044-8FE00D709CB6/Piedmont Road Apple TV.app> (loaded)' with name 'kQf-Ef-Nxz-view-nK4-c0-71Y'"   0x0000600000c73d50
```

I have put in breakpoints, but it doesn't seem to help. Anyone have an idea what got changed with tvOS 17.2 to cause this?

I have absolutely nothing in my AppDelegate for the app, except for initializing Parse server and configuration. The app simply loads the Main.storyboard. I have the name set up in Info.plist. I did notice that after updating Xcode, it no longer gives you the option to set the interface in the General settings of the Target. Could this be something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, there is issue with relationship `"secondary view controller"` of `UISplitViewController` on `Storyboard`. So I fixed the bug by **deleting** the former and **loading** the `"secondaryViewController"` programmatically instead of the `Storyboard`.

[image: storyboard image]

Comment: Were you getting the same kind of error where it said it couldn't load a nib from storyboard, and then gave a name that doesn't actually exist?

Comment: Ok, I finally found the scene that had that the weird characters as Object ID, and it was the same as this. Changed it to show segue instead of secondaryViewController and it fixed it. Definitely need to have apple address this change.